# Regarding the Route Inspection Problem (Chinese Postman Problem)

Tags: graph-theory

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) article on the problem states that for a non-Eulerian graph, "the optimization problem is to find the fewest number of edges to add to the graph so that the resulting multigraph does have an Eulerian circuit." This seems to be misleading. Shouldn't it instead say something along the lines of "finding the minimal edge set $T$, such that by adding parallel edge for each $(x, y) \in T$ the resulting multigraph has an Eulerian circuit"?

The wikipedia article goes on to discuss T-joins, and saying the smallest T-join consists of $\frac{1}{2} |T|$ paths. Doesn't this not hold for the diamond graph? Clearly the diamond graph can be made to have an Eulerian circuit by adding an edge between the two degree-3 nodes, but since that edge does not initially exist, wouldn't the original problem just be counting the number of odd-degree vertices?

I think I'm more confused by the Wikipedia article than anything. Is it misleading, or am I confused on some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first paragraph: I agree, the formulation is misleading. It could be salvaged by inserting e.g. "parallel to existing edges". If you replace it by your alternative, you probably shouldn't use $T$ for an edge set, since it's later used for a vertex set.

About your second paragraph: I'm not sure I understand your criticism. It sounds like you might be taking $|T|$ to be the vertex count of the entire graph – it's just the vertex count of $T$. The article doesn't explain this very clearly, but $T$ is here taken to be the set of vertices of odd order. In the diamond graph, that means $|T|=2$, so $\frac12|T|=1$, so there's no contradiction with the fact that adding one edge yields a Eulerian circuit. In any case, the $\frac12|T|$ bound is correct, since each of the $|T|$ vertices that are of odd order in the induced subgraph of the edge set must have at least one edge incident.

Comment: This clears things up for me, thank you!